# arcpy.Delete_management not deleting

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy

I'm struggling with deleting an mxd in a for loop. My code is:

```
    import arcpy, glob, os, datetime, time
    from time import strftime

    for filename3 in glob.glob(os.path.join(folderPath, "*.mxd")):

    fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename3)
    basename, filename2 = os.path.split(fullpath)

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filename3)

    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        basename, filename2 = os.path.split(fullpath)


        (shortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(filename2)

    mxd.saveACopy(draftloc + "\\" + "SentToDraftOn(" + strftime("%d%b%y %Hh%Mm%Ss") + ")"+ "_" + shortname + extension)
    arcpy.Delete_management(mxd)
```

I'm trying to do some processing on each mxd in a directory and then I want to saveACopy to a new location and then delete the old mxd. I keep getting the following traceback error:

> Object: Error in executing tool

I think it's an indentation thing, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Delete_management` deletes a file on the disk. `mxd` as you have it is a reference to a map object in Python (which happens to reference the .mxd on the disk you want to delete. Instead you want to delete the path (which you have as `filename3`).

Instead you should use:

```
del mxd #deletes the reference in Python
arcpy.Delete_management(filename3) #deletes the file off the disk
```